# Check the connection in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm trying to tell the user to check the connection via a label if there was a issue, and if the connection working again the label gonna disappear. My code works fine but when I turn off wifi manually the label doesn't show up unless i close and open the app again!! I'm confused on what to put on on my code to check it every time without closing and opening the app?

```
func InternetCheck () -> Bool {

    var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
    zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: zeroAddress))
    zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)

    let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(to: &zeroAddress) {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: sockaddr.self, capacity: 1) {zeroSockAddress in
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, zeroSockAddress)
        }
    }

    var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
    if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
        return false
    }
    let isReachable = flags.contains(.reachable)
    let needsConnection = flags.contains(.connectionRequired)
    return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
}

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if InternetCheck() == false {

       stsLabel.text = "Check your Internet Connection"

    } else {
      stsLabel.isHidden = true
}
}
```

Comment: You call `InternetCheck()` only once. There is no "listener", you check it only once on `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call InternetCheck() in viewDidLoad() and there is no listener for it and it will call once. Try something like this:

```
let reachabilityManager = Alamofire.NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    listenForReachability()
}


func listenForReachability() {
    self.reachabilityManager?.listener = { [weak self]status in
        switch status {
        case .notReachable:
            self?.showNoInternetConnectionAlert()
        case .unknown :
            print("It is unknown whether the network is reachable")
        case .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi):
           //do sth
        case .reachable(.wwan):
           // do sth
        }
    }
    self.reachabilityManager?.startListening()
}
```

Comment: don't forget the `super.viewDidLoad`

Comment: Merc Hasti, This did just what I wanted!